# null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useRef')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, native

I NEED HELP WITH THIS PROBLEM.

I tried to delete node modules, install it again. I have tried to rewrite the code, and use the useRef component different.

COULD YOU HELP ME WITH IT PLEASE?

[[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wiUY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr12j.png)

```
const flatListRef = React.useRef();
const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

const onViewChangeRef = React.useRef(({viewableItems, changed}) => {
```

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
  {index == 0 && <Walkthrough1 />}
  {index == 1 && <Walkthrough2 animate={walkthrough2Animate || false} />}
  {index == 2 && <Walkthrough3 animate={walkthrough3Animate} />}
  {index == 3 && <Walkthrough4 animate={walkthrough4Animate} />}
</View>
```

Comment: you can use redux ?? with react native ?

Comment: yes, I can. why?

Comment: You can use class component or function component??

Answer (score 0):

try to start the ref as null and then use the reference inside of your Element
exp:

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null)

<Input 
   ref(inputRef)
   placeholder="..."
/>
```